# SQL Question regarding dates and times

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I want to create an SQL Query for a SQLite3 DB.

In my table I have the following sample data

```
7/1/2011   8:00   LOGIN
7/1/2011   10:12  LOGOFF
7/1/2011   10:20  LOGIN
7/1/2011   17:15  LOGOFF
7/2/2011   9:00   LOGIN
7/3/2011   10:00  LOGIN
7/3/2011   20:00  LOGOFF
```

basically I want to only get the first LOGIN entry per date and the last LOGOFF entry for the same date (if available)

So I want the query to produce

```
7/1/2011   8:00   LOGIN
7/1/2011   17:15  LOGOFF
7/2/2011   9:00   LOGIN
7/3/2011   10:00  LOGIN
7/3/2011   20:00  LOGOFF
```

Is is also possible to calculate the difference in Time with the desired output table?

IE/ on 7/1/2011 would be 9:15

Comment: Are you dates and times stored in separate fields?

Comment: Yes. Dates and times are separate fields. The Time field may include seconds (which was not displayed in the posting above). The field in the DB is a VARCHAR but it holds a date and time.

Comment: "Is is also possible to calculate the difference in Time with the desired output table?" Yes it is but which row would you want it on? The login or the logoff

Comment: I can see that the data may contain a single login entry without the corresponding logoff entry on the same day. Is it also possible that there is a login entry, then a logoff, then a login again and no logoff? If so, you might need a sophisticated solution to return consistent results.

Comment: In SQLite, timestamps need to be in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) format in order for the date/time functions to work.

Comment: @Andridy - yes its possible because if they push and hold the power button (unplug from power source or disconnect from Network via unplugging Ethernet), the logoff script doesn't run and capture the data. The bigger concern is the output table (even if the time difference is not calculated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your columns are named `Date, Time, Action`, this is what you need:

```
select Date,
       case Action 
         when 'LOGIN' then Min(Time)
         when 'LOGOFF' then Max(Time)
       end as ActionTime,
       Action 
from YourTable
group by Date, Action
```

**Update**

For calculating the difference, you might want to "flatten" the rows of a day to a single row:

```
select Date, MinLoginTime, MaxLogoffTime, MaxLogoffTime - MinLoginTime as Diff
from
(
select Date,
       Min(
           case Action 
               when 'LOGIN' then Time
               else null
           end
       ) as MinLoginTime,
       Max(
           case Action 
               when 'LOGOFF' then Time
               else null
           end
       ) as MaxLogoffTime
from YourTable
group by Date
) YourDT
```

Some considerations:

- If you don't have MinLoginTime OR MaxLogoffTime, `Diff` will be null
- You will probably have to work on formatting `Diff`. Do some research on that for SQLite, every RDBMS has its particularities on that matter.

Comment: The first query gives this error message with SQLite3 "aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you take them on the same line for every day?

```
SELECT 
  LogIns.Date, LogInHour, LogOffHour
FROM
  (SELECT Date, MIN(hour) LogInHour
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE action = 'LOGIN'
   GROUP BY Date) LogIns
 LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Date, MAX(hour) LogOffHour
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE action = 'LOGOFF'
   GROUP BY Date) LogOffs
 ON LogIns.Date = LogOffs.Date
```

I used LEFT JOIN because you may have a LOGIN in a day but no LOGOFF.

Comment: I am confused about this query.